# Determining the number of solutions of the equation $y^2 = x^3 + x^2 + 5$ in $\mathbb{Z}/p^k \mathbb{Z}$ in function of $k$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, congruences

I found a question that asked me to discuss the number of solutions of the equation $y^2 = x^3 + x^2 + 5$  in $\mathbb{Z}/p^k \mathbb{Z}$ in function of $k$.

I would like to use the multivariate Lemma of Hensel-Rychlick for $p$-adic numbers. Suppose that $N$ equals the number of solutions of $y^2 = x^3 + x^2 +5$ in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ such that there exist some $i \in \{x, y\}$ such that $\frac{d f(a)}{di} \neq 0$ where $f(a) \equiv 0 \mod p$. For each of these $N$ solutions there exist a $b \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ such that $f(b) = 0$. 
This essentially means that for each $b$ and  $k \in \mathbb{N}_{>0}$, there exists a solution for $y^2 = x^3 + x^2 + 5$ in $\mathbb{Z}/p^k \mathbb{Z}$. 
So there are $N$ solutions of $y^2 = x^3 + x^2 +5$ in $\mathbb{Z}/p^k \mathbb{Z}$.

What do you guys think of this answer?

Comment: Did you actually try to lift the equation from $\mathbb{Z}/(p^k\mathbb{Z})$ to $\mathbb{Z}/(p^{k+1}\mathbb{Z})$ by simply expanding it?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, could you please expand?

Comment: If $(x, y)$ is a solution $\bmod p^k$ then try when $(x + a p^k, y + b p^k)$ is a "lifted" solution $\bmod p^{k+1}$.

Comment: Should it not be according th Hensel's Lemma?

Comment: That's my point: just see what happens instead of relying on magic.